# Eloquont Laravel filtrar anidadamente

Tags: laravel, buscador

estoy aprendiendo con eloquent y estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

```
$ubicacionesObtenida = Ubicacion::with('properties.category')
            ->ubicacion($ubicacion)
            ->get();
```

Esto me trae correctamente todas las ubicaciones con las propiedades y las categorías de las propiedades. Lo que necesito es filtrar esas categorias, algo así:

```
$ubicacionesObtenida = Ubicacion::with('properties.category')
        ->where('nombre', casa)
            ->ubicacion($ubicacion)
            ->get();
```

MODELO PROPIEDADES

```
public function ubicacion(){
    return $this->hasMany(Ubicacion::class);
}


public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

MODELO UBICACION

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}

public function area(){
    //hasOne: una ubicacion tiene un area
    return $this->hasOne(Area::class);
}
```

MODELO CATEGORIA

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}
```

Pero me indica error y entiendo que nombre es buscado en un campo de ubicación ¿es posible filtrar en category?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los `Model` relacionados a tu consulta, para que se pueda ver como están las conexiones en modelos.

Comment: @CesarRomero hola estimado, muchas gracias, agregué lo solicitado por  favor si necesitas algo más me avisas. Estoy googleando peor no termino de entender como  puedo llevar a cabo esta consulta.

Comment: Si ubicación tiene `belongsToMany` con respecto de propiedades, entonces propiedades en su método ubicación también debería ser `belongsToMany` y haría falta la tabla pivote en medio de estás dos

Comment: Hola @BetaM disculpa soy nuevo con estos conceptos de eloquent y de relaciones. Entiendo que una propiedad tiene una ubicación y una ubicación puede tener muchas propiedades, por lo tanto es uno a muchos y muchos a uno, a lo mejor en el modelo Ubicación debería ser hasMany, ¿Que opinas? de verdad muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Betam agregué en este ejemplo el modelo viejo, lo edite a como lo tengo actualmente. hasMany tiene  ubicación.